# Portable way of determining font properties (mono and standard .net)

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, mono

Does anyone know a way to determine if a font is monospace and the width and height of a single character (only relevant if it is monospace).
The important requirement is that it works with mono and microsoft implementations of .net .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to choose which GUI Toolkit you are targeting.

Fonts aren't abstracted in a toolkit-independent way, AFAIK.

For WinForms, [TextRenderer.MeasureText method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) used with "iii" and "www"  strings can help you guess if the font is monospaced and which is the probable 'fixed' width of a char cell, bu it may not work right for very small point sizes...